# Final render image looking distorted with weird wave patterns all around

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, particles

I'm a beginner in Blender and was following a tutorial. Everything was going fine until the render part. **My final image is distorted (especially on the right side, don't know why) and I have no clue how to fix it**.

Following the tutorial, I used Cycles to render.

One thing I noticed... on the tutorial, he uses a volumetric effect to make the light leave a path. I tried disabling it to see if it has something to do with it and the render looked fine. I just rendered without it and turned down the intensity of the sunlight from 40 to 5 (it was high because of the fog).

I'll leave here the link of the tutorial and how my final image ended up like with and without the fog.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mR641cA2zT4

Also, english is not my first language, so sorry if I didn't explain well.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try reducing any *displacement node* Scale on the tile material.  In face, be sure there is nothing connected to the displacement material output for your tile.

Answer (score 0):

Those wiggly artifacts happen when the denoiser is working with a very noisy image. Increasing the sample count should help, but the render will take longer.

Effects like volumetrics can result in a noisier image which is why the render is cleaner when you disable that.